# Convert raw RGB byte sequence into a HxWx3 image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb

I have raw RGB (8 bit/channel) data of a WxH image, where bytes are specified in the (row-major) order:

> r[1,1] g[1,1] b[1,1] r[1,2] g[1,2] b[1,2] ... r[H,W] g[H,W] b[H,W]

e.g. for a 256x256 RGB image, I have an 196608x1 uint8 array.

In order to convert this data to be used with MATLAB functions like `imshow` I have to reshape and then permute dims:

```
% imgvec: 196608x1 uint8

img = permute(reshape(imgvec, 3, H, W), [3 2 1])

% img: 256x256x3 uint8
```

is there a more straightforward way to it? This layout of raw RGB data is so common, perhaps there is a specific function to convert to/from it...

Comment: Just `reshape(imgvec, H, W, 3)`, or am I missing something?

Comment: fferri, your approach seems to me to be the right one. @TomiAarnio Your approach will put the color channels out of order. For yours to work, the original vector would have to be ordered with all of the red channel first, followed by the green channel...

Comment: Ah, of course, the Fortran order. This is not Python. /facepalm